# A problem that a footnote appears on the page before the footnote mark

Tags: page-breaking

A long footnote goes before the page which has the word footnoted.  Of course, I can use a \newpage to correct this "error", but I want to know whether there is an easier way to avoid this problem at all.
Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

**editor's note**: The code below has been edited for being compilable (`\parindent` must be followed by length specification and `\interfootnotelinepenalty` by  a number specification)

```
%!TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}   

\usepackage{graphicx}   

\usepackage{float}      

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[indentfirst=false]{quoting}

\usepackage{bigfoot}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{footalt}

\def\thefootalt{\fnsymbol{footalt}}

\MakeSortedPerPage{footalt}

\WithSuffix\def\footnotedefault'{\refstepcounter{footalt}

\Footnotedefault{\thefootalt}}

\usepackage{footmisc}  

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[arabic]

\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[Roman]

\DeclareNewFootnote{C}[alph]

\DeclareNewFootnote{D}[roman]

\DeclareNewFootnote{E}[fnsymbol]

\DeclareNewFootnote{F}[Alph]

\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteC}

\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteD}

\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteE}

\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteF}

\newcommand{\fa}{\footnoteA}

\newcommand{\fb}{\footnoteB}

\newcommand{\fc}{\footnoteC}

\newcommand{\fd}{\footnoteD}

\newcommand{\fe}{\footnoteE}

\newcommand{\ff}{\footnoteF}

\newcommand{\fr}{\footref}

\newcommand{\lb}{\label}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

% \def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\let\old@makefnmark\@makefnmark
\newcommand{\@newmakefnmark}{\hbox{\kern.1em \@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\kern-.1em}}
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{\@makefnmark}{\old@makefnmark}{}{}
%

\makeatother

\makeatletter

\let\@makefnmark\@newmakefnmark
\setcounter{footnote}{0}

\makeatother

\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule

\def\footnoterule{\oldfootnoterule\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}

\newcommand{\tit}{\textit}

\newcommand{\tbf}{\textbf}

\newcommand{\bt}{\bfseries}



\begin{document}

\sloppy

% \interfootnotelinepenalty % MISSING SPEC

\begin{quoting} %\parindent MISSING LENGTH
{\it ... gṛhṇāti \fr{132}tān\fc{\lb{132}{\it tān} PVA2, PVm : {\it tat} PVs, PVA1. PVAms (220b5) is in very bad condition here, but can be possibly read as {\it tān}.}  punaḥ / \\
nādhyakṣam iti ced eṣa kuto bhedaḥ \fr{133}samarthayoḥ\fc{\lb{133}PVAms (220b5) is unclear here, 
%\includegraphics[width=0.10\linewidth]{009.png}, MISSING IMAGE
but I can still read {\it ma}, not {\it mā}. Although PVA1 (p. 129, l. 12) and PVA2 (p. 439, l. 11) read {\it ma}, Frauwallner corrects it in his PVA2 by adding a long vowel sign after {\it ma}. PVs (p. 90) and M (Mms 49b5) read {\it mā}. Considering that there is no difference between the meaning of {\it samartha} and {\it samārtha}, I follow PVA.}  //} {\bf 453b2cd}\\

{\it … / gal te de la 'dzin byed kyang / \\
/ mngon sum nyid ni min zhe na /\\
/ don mtshungs tha dad de gang las /} {\bf PVt}\\

{\it … / gal te de la 'dzin byed kyang / \\
/ mngon sum nyid ni min zhe na /\\
/ don mtsungs de dag cis tha dad /} {\bf PVr}
\end{quoting}

[Opponent\fa{Kedrup identifies the opponent in this verse by names Bye Brag Pa (Vaiśeṣika), Ring Pa Can (Naiyāyika), and Grangs Can Pa (Sāṃkhya)\fd{Cf. PVVke, p. 407.}}:] One grasps these [pleasure or pain belonging to another series - {\it santāna} -] indirectly. [Proponent:] how can this difference exist between these two (i.e., the experience of one's own series and the inference of the cognition of another series) which have the similar object?

\begin{quoting} %\parindent MISSING LENGTH

{\it adṛṣṭaikārthayogādeḥ saṃvido niyamo yadi / \\
sarvathānyo na gṛhṇīyāt saṃvidbhedo 'py apoditaḥ //} {\bf 454}\\

{\it / ma mthong don gcig ldan sogs kyis /\\
/ gal te myong \fr{134}ba\fc{\lb{134}{\it ba} D : {\it ba'i} P.} \fr{135}nges\fc{\lb{135}corr. : {\it des} D, P.} yin na / \\
/ gzhan ni rnam kun 'dzin mi 'gyur /\\
/ myong ba'i dbye ba'ang \fr{136}bsal\fc{\lb{136}{\it bsal} P : {\it gsal} D.} zin to /} {\bf PVt}\\

{\it / gal te mthong med las don gcig /\\
/ lhan sogs myong bar nges na ni / \\
/ gzhan gyis rnam kun mi 'dzin cing /\\
/ myong ba'i tha dad dag kyang \fr{137}bsal\fc{\lb{137}corr. : {\it gsal} D, P.} /} {\bf PVr}
\end{quoting}

If [the opponent says:] because of the unseen [cause which is characterized as pure or impure,]\fa{
``The unseen thing ({\it adṛṣṭa})" is interpreted as ``the pure and impure causes (t. {\it chos dang chos ma yi pa'i mtshan nyid}; sk. {\it śubhāśubhādilakṣaṇādeḥ}) by Devendrabuddhi, Ravigupta and Manorathanandin.\fd{Cf. De, 249b1 D; R, 157a1 and M1, p. 253, l. 20.}

A similar statement is found in {\it Vaiśeṣikasūtra} and its commentary where Kaṇāda and Candrānanda explain the distinction of the consciousness: {\it dharmāc ca /} (VS, 9, 24) {\it ananubhūtārthaviṣayam api svapnajñānaṃ śubhāśubhasūcakaṃ \fr{138}dharmāc\ff{\lb{138}VS reads {\it dharmāt}.} ca śabdād adharmāc ceti /} (p. 70, 17-18).
} the inherence in the same thing\fa{
Prajñākaragupta and Manorathanandin interpret {\it ekārthayoga} as {\it ekārthasamvāya}.\fd{Cf. PVA2, p. 439, ll. 20-21; M1, p. 253, l. 20.}  Kaṇāda, in his VS 10.10, the section on the explanation of the division of inference, makes a similar statement: {\it ekāthasamavāyiṣu kāraṇāntareṣu darśanād ekadeśa ity ekasmin /}\fd{VS, p. 74, l. 11.}.
} and so on, [which exists for one who perceives the suffering and happiness in one's own series]\fa{
Cf. M1, p. 253, ll. 20-21: {\it...svasantānavartisukhagrāhikāyāḥ...}
} etc.,\fa{
Devendrabuddhi and Ravigupta specify that the word ``etc." includes other causes accepted by the opponent, such as the pleasure and displeasure ({\it dga' ba dang mi dga' ba la sogs ba}) of Iśvara, etc.\fd{Cf. De D 249b3; R D 157a2.} Different consequences out of such emotions of Iśvara are further explained as a complex of vivid perceiving of happiness and dull perceiving of suffering, or otherwise.\fd{Cf. Ś: {\it / dbang phyug dga' ba dang mi dga' ba la sogs pa zhes bya ba la / dbang phyug dga' ba las bde ba gsal bar dmigs shing sdug bsngal mi gsal bar dmigs pa'o // mi dga' ba las ni bzlog pa'o /} D 238b4ff.)}
} there is a restriction of awareness, [Proponent:] the other [person\fa{
Note that Kedrup interprets {\it gzhan} ({\it anya}) as ``the previous happiness and so on which is substantively different from itself (i.e., the subsequent cognition in the one's own series)" (\tit {… rang las rdzas \tbf{gzhan} du gyur ba'i bde sogs snga ma rnams …} PVVke, p. 408), while Devendrabuddhi (De D 249b4), Ravigupta (R D 157a3) and Manorathanandin (M1, p. 253, l. 21) interpret {\it gzhan} or {\it anya} as ``a man ({\it skyes bu}) different from the enjoyer ({\it bhoktṛ}) who has the unseen causes which bring the restricted experience of one's own suffering or happiness"\fd{
Cf. De D 249b4: {\it / gzhan gyi rnam kun mi 'dzin cing // skyes bu dang 'brel ba can gyi bde ba la sogs pa gzhan rnam pa thams cad du rnam pa 'ga' zhig kyang mi 'dzin pa nyid du 'gyur ro /}\\
R D 157a2ff.: {\it de'i tshe ma mthong ba la sogs pa'i stobs kyis rnam pa thams cad du rnam pa gang gis kyang skyes bu gzhan gyis pha rol gyi bde ba la sogs pa 'dzin pa ma yin no zhes bya bar 'dir ci ste mi 'gyur /}\\
M1, p. 253, l. 21: {\it …tenānyasya na bhoktṛteti…}
}.  These two kinds of interpretations lead to two different explanations of PV 3.454c.  Except Kedrup, other commentators including Gyaltsab explain this {\it pāda} as follows:

In order to distinguish the enjoyer's experience and the inference of another person, the opponent presents two reasons in the first two {\it pādas}, namely, (1) the unseen forces belonging to the enjoyer and (2) the inherence in the same thing, i.e., the soul.  Dharmakīrti replies in PV 3.454c: such reasons would also bring about an absurd consequence that there would be no cognition of another person's cognition at all, because no one can have the unseen cause and inherence in another mind series.  That is to say, in PV 3.454c, Dharmakīrti uses the major premise used in his opponent's argument—if there are no unseen forces (i.e., the pure or impure action done previously) or inherence in one thing, then there is no perceiving ({\it √grah}) of feeling.

However, Kedrup keenly observes that according to PV 3.453b2cd, the word ``perceiving" in the opponent's argument should be specified as the experience of one's own feeling. He further indicates that if we accept the premise implied in PV 3.454c (because Buddhists also accept that there would not be any experience of suffering and happiness if there is no karmic force accumulated previously\fd{
PVVke, p. 409: {\it / thal 'gyur 'di'i khyab pa de 'dzin pa'i rgyur gyur ba'i sngon gyi las med pa la de mi 'dzin pas ma khyab na / de myong ba'i rgyu gyur ba'i sngon gyi las med pa la de mi myong bas khyab pa yod pa bud /}
}), then there would be an absurd consequence that the Buddha cannot perceive the cognition of another person because he does not have any karmic force in his mind series. But if we accept the premise on condition that {\it √grah} is specified as experience in this case, then Dharmakīrti's refutation would become problematic.  Accordingly, Kedrup gives his distinct explanation of PV 3.454cd as follows:
\begin{quotation}
The subsequent cognition in the mind series of Lha Spyin (Devadatta), cannot perceive or experience your previous happiness and so on at all, which are substantively different from that [subsequent experience]. This is because the inherent relation, which makes the subsequent experience and the previous pleasure inherent in the Self, is not established. [The reason is established] because if such relation is established, they must exist at the same time.  Further, although there is the difference for [whether the cognition can] be experienced or not due to the influence of the previous karmic action as in the case that [you claim that] the object is perceived without a form [passed to the cognition] but through the direct contact [with the cognition], [such argument] too is rejected by the valid reasoning in rejecting [the view that] ``depending on the unseen [action] another object would arise in [proximity or distance]"\fd{
{\it / gal te der yang mthong med la / brten nas gzugs gzhan 'byung 'gyur na /} = PV 3.412cd: {\it tatrāpy adṛṣṭam āśritya bhaved rūpāntaraṃ yadi /} On the other hand, Manorathanandin seems to indicate that {\it apodita} refers to PV 3.407ab, because only in those two {\it pādas} is the phrase {\it vyaktāvyakta} cited in M found. (Cf. M1, p. 253, l. 25.) Ravigupta also proposes a citation—{\it rigs zhes bya ba phan tshun rten}—to which {\it apodita} refers, but I cannot find the source of this statement.
}.\fd{Cf. PVVke, p. 408: {\it / lha sbyin gyi bde sogs la rtog pa'i lha sbyin rang rgyud kyi blo phyi ma chos can / khyod kyis rang las rdzas gzhan du gyur ba'i bde sogs snga ma rnams ni rnam pa kun tu 'dzin cing myong bar mi 'gyur bar thal / de dag dang bdag gi don gcig la ldan pa'i 'brel ba ma grub pa'i phyir te / bdag rtag pa'i don gcig la ldan pa'i 'brel ba grub na dus mnyam yin dgos pa'i phyir / gzhan yang yul rnam med thug phrad du 'dzin par mtshungs pa la sngon gyi las dbang gis myong ma myong gi dbye ba yod pa'ang / gal te der yang mthong med la / brten nas gzugs gzhan 'byung 'gyur na / zhes sogs 'gog pa'i skabs su rigs pa yang dag gis bsal zin to //}}
\end{quotation}

According to this explanation, PV 3.454c is the reply to the defense of {\it ekārthayoga}, while PV 3.454d is the response to the defense of {\it adṛṣṭa}.

}] would not grasp [the restricted happiness] in any way. The difference in cognitions [which have the same object] has also been rejected.


\end{document}
```

Comment: in normal situations the long footnote should have been split across the pages. Do you use a ``\parbox`` or ``minipage`` in the footnote? anyway, please extend your question with  a mwe.

Comment: Or load [bigfoot](http://ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot)!

Comment: @jfbu No, I do not use those two.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem with a very small document containing only some text and the footnote?

Comment: @jfbu Thank you for your help. A part of my paper is added.  You would find that the footnotes n. 2-6 appear before the text they remark.

Comment: I have compiled your code on my computer and I have observe no problem. Notice that your code has errors: you use `\parindent` but it must be `\setlength{\parindent}{<value>}`. And you use `\interfootnotelinepenalty` but it must be `\interfootnotelinepenalty=<number>\relax`. Also I needed to remove the `\includegraphics` because I don't have the image.

Comment: perhaps you want `\interfootnotelinepenalty\widowpenalty` ? (copied from a sample code in bigfoot documentation)

Comment: @jfbu Well, thank you for your time. However, the problem remains on mine, as the pdf shown above.

Comment: it is hard to diagnose your problem as it compiles fine on my computer (with TL2016). Have you tried the code as edited above (i.e. with the two `\parindent` removed and the includegraphcis and the interfootnotelinepenalty) ?

Comment: @jfbu Thanks again.  Since I am a newbie in this field, I don’t quite understand every details of a command, such as the <number> in \interfootnotelinepenalty=<number>. I use \interfootnotelinepenalty simply because it can make loog footnote continue to the next page. I use \parindent in some quotation is for those verses appearing in between the “quoting” site without any indentation, but other paragraphs in my paper need to be set as fist-line-indent.

Comment: `\interfootnotelinepenalty` by itself creates a compilation error; your software was hiding it from you. It needs an "assignement". For example `\interfootnotelinepenalty\widowpenalty` knowing that `\widowpenalty` is defined by LaTeX to hold value `150`. Similarly `\parindent` alone makes no sense and must be followed by a dimension, or LaTeX provides `\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}` more cumbersome syntax. Notice that LaTeX provides no syntax for count's like the penalties discussed above. It defines a subclass called counters which are count's with a name starting with `\c@...` hence hidden.

Comment: @samcarter yes, it is because the subjection here is not the solution. For example, even in the edited sample presented above, if you change the \package{footmisc} in \package[hang]{footmisc}, you will see the problem still.