# Problem: a long footnote appears before the page where the footnote mark appears

Tags: footnotes, bigfoot

This is indeed an old question I had in
[enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333435/a-problem-that-a-footnote-appears-on-the-page-before-the-footnote-mark)

and is not yet solved. This time I offer a small example as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany,openbib,draft]{book} 
\usepackage[total={5in, 8in}]{geometry} 
\usepackage[ruled]{bigfoot}

\newcounter{footalt}
\def\thefootalt{\fnsymbol{footalt}}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footalt}
\WithSuffix\def\footnotedefault'{\refstepcounter{footalt}
    \Footnotedefault{\thefootalt}}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}  
\renewcommand {\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}} % 改 \footnote 為 alph
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnote}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[arabic]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{C}[roman]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{D}[Alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{E}[Roman]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{F}[fnsymbol]
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteB}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteC}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteE}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteF}
%\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteF}
\newcommand{\fa}{\footnoteA}
\newcommand{\fb}{\footnoteB}
\newcommand{\fc}{\footnoteC}
\newcommand{\fd}{\footnoteD}
\newcommand{\fe}{\footnoteE}
\newcommand{\ff}{\footnoteF}
\newcommand{\fr}{\footref}
\newcommand{\lb}{\label}
% 章節footnote連數
%\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter} 
%設置space between footnote mark and footnote {in [hang]}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{4mm} 

%%以下第二部分加寬備註號和注文的之間寬度
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% \def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\let\old@makefnmark\@makefnmark
\newcommand{\@newmakefnmark}{\hbox{\kern.1em \@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\kern-.1em}}
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{\@makefnmark}{\old@makefnmark}{}{}
%
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\let\@makefnmark\@newmakefnmark
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\makeatother
%調整備註和備註分界線的距離
\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule
\def\footnoterule{\oldfootnoterule\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}



\begin{document}


    \chapter{Abstrakt}

    \begin{verse}
        Selbstbewusstsein ist eine der zentralen 

        \ttfamily ttfamily śiḍṭthṇṃḥ Grundsätze im Yogācāra. Eini-ge Befürworter \\
        \sffamily sffamily śiḍṭthṇṃḥ des Selbstbewusstseins,  wie Devendrabuddhi, ist eine der zentralen Grundsätz\\
        \rmfamily romanfamily śiḍṭthṇṃḥ romanfamily Kamala-śīla und Mokṣākaragupta, sagen sogar, 
    \end{verse}
    \slshape Selbstbewusstsein ist eine der zentralen Grundsätze im Yogācāra. Eini-ge Befürworter des Selbstbewusstseins, wie Devendrabuddhi, Kamala-śīla und Mokṣākaragupta, sagen sogar, dass die Behauptung, dass das Bewusstsein sich selbst\footnote{
    testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing
    testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing
    testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing

}
    \upshape
    nicht bewusst ist, kontraintuitiv ist. Die Aussage impliziert, dass das Selbstbewusstsein weit verbreitet in unserem Alltag akzeptiert ist. Doch in philosophischen und akademischen Studien ist die Kontroverse über die Existenz des Selbstbewusstseins für mehr als fünfzehn Jahrhunderte fortgesetzt. Unter den Gelehrten, die an dieser Debatte beteiligt waren, trug Dharmakīrti 147 Verse im dritten Kapitel seines Meisterwerks \textit{Pramāṇavārttika} (im Folgenden PV) zur Erklärung und dem Beweis des Selbstbewusstseins bei.

\end{document}
```

The sample shows the problem clearly. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If I comment package `bigfoot` and the other stuff you had related to footnotes I get the result you want.

Please see the following mwe (for documentation I did not delete the commented part)

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany,openbib,draft]{book} 

\usepackage[total={5in, 8in}]{geometry} 
%\usepackage[ruled]{bigfoot}

%\newcounter{footalt}
%\def\thefootalt{\fnsymbol{footalt}}
%\MakeSortedPerPage{footalt}
%\WithSuffix\def\footnotedefault'{\refstepcounter{footalt}
    %\Footnotedefault{\thefootalt}}
%%\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
%%\setlength{\footnotemargin}{4mm} 
%
%\renewcommand {\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}} % 改 \footnote 為 alph
%\MakeSortedPerPage{footnote}
%\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[arabic]
%\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}[alph]
%\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{C}[roman]
%\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{D}[Alph]
%\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{E}[Roman]
%\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{F}[fnsymbol]
%\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteB}
%\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteC}
%\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteE}
%\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteF}
%%\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteF}
%\newcommand{\fa}{\footnoteA}
%\newcommand{\fb}{\footnoteB}
%\newcommand{\fc}{\footnoteC}
%\newcommand{\fd}{\footnoteD}
%\newcommand{\fe}{\footnoteE}
%\newcommand{\ff}{\footnoteF}
%\newcommand{\fr}{\footref}
%\newcommand{\lb}{\label}
%% 章節footnote連數
%%\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter} 
%%設置space between footnote mark and footnote {in [hang]}
%
%
%%%以下第二部分加寬備註號和注文的之間寬度
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\makeatletter
%% \def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
%\let\old@makefnmark\@makefnmark
%\newcommand{\@newmakefnmark}{\hbox{\kern.1em \@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\kern-.1em}}
%\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{\@makefnmark}{\old@makefnmark}{}{}
%%
%\makeatother
%\makeatletter
%\let\@makefnmark\@newmakefnmark
%\setcounter{footnote}{0}
%\makeatother
%%調整備註和備註分界線的距離
%\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule
%\def\footnoterule{\oldfootnoterule\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}



\begin{document}


    \chapter{Abstrakt}

    \begin{verse}
        Selbstbewusstsein ist eine der zentralen 

        \ttfamily ttfamily śiḍṭthṇṃḥ Grundsätze im Yogācāra. Eini-ge Befürworter \\
        \sffamily sffamily śiḍṭthṇṃḥ des Selbstbewusstseins,  wie Devendrabuddhi, ist eine der zentralen Grundsätz\\
        \rmfamily romanfamily śiḍṭthṇṃḥ romanfamily Kamala-śīla und Mokṣākaragupta, sagen sogar, 
    \end{verse}
    \slshape Selbstbewusstsein ist eine der zentralen Grundsätze im Yogācāra. Eini-ge Befürworter des Selbstbewusstseins, wie Devendrabuddhi, Kamala-śīla und Mokṣākaragupta, sagen sogar, dass die Behauptung, dass das Bewusstsein sich selbst\footnote{
    testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing
    testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing
    testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing

}
    \upshape
    nicht bewusst ist, kontraintuitiv ist. Die Aussage impliziert, dass das Selbstbewusstsein weit verbreitet in unserem Alltag akzeptiert ist. Doch in philosophischen und akademischen Studien ist die Kontroverse über die Existenz des Selbstbewusstseins für mehr als fünfzehn Jahrhunderte fortgesetzt. Unter den Gelehrten, die an dieser Debatte beteiligt waren, trug Dharmakīrti 147 Verse im dritten Kapitel seines Meisterwerks \textit{Pramāṇavārttika} (im Folgenden PV) zur Erklärung und dem Beweis des Selbstbewusstseins bei.

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: resulting pdf]